# JPanel background image not showing

Tags: java, background, jpanel

I use GUI designer to create a `JPanel` class. I am trying to add a background image to it but it shows nothing. It can show the `JLabel` if I put a `JLabel` on the `JPanel` somewhere.

I don't think the image path is a problem because I can show the other images saved in this path on the other panel (using `JLabel`'s setIcon() method).

The background image's dimension is 1920x1080.

I searched a lot of posts here already. Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong?

```
public class MenuPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    private final Image background;

    public MenuPanel() {
        initComponents();
        background = new ImageIcon("/program/img/bg.jpg").getImage();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);    
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                      
    private void initComponents() {

        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(800, 650));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 800, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 650, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }     
}

public class GUI {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 650));
        MenuPanel m = new MenuPanel();
        frame.add(m);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon-java.lang.String-).  The argument to the ImageIcon constructor is a filename.  Does your computer have a file at "/program/img/bg.jpg"?

Answer (score -2):

You can try to implement the sample from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Panelwithbackgroundimage.htm).

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImageTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("images/background.png").getImage());

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

  private Image img;

  public ImagePanel(String img) {
    this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
  }

  public ImagePanel(Image img) {
    this.img = img;
    Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setMinimumSize(size);
    setMaximumSize(size);
    setSize(size);
    setLayout(null);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
  }

}
```